# Android: keyboard numeric changes automatically to keyboard text alone

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a simple item renderer for a standard ListView. In this item renderer I have 2 EditText configure like that:

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="40dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="number"
   android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
   android:text="8"/>
```

When I click the first on one of these EditText, the numeric keyboard appears 1 second, then changes automatically by the standard text keyboard... I don't know why! If I click a new time on one of these, the numeric keyboard appears and it's ok (no change). Actually, the problem appears if there is no open keyboard.

Have you got an idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

How about check if your java code have some setInputType() on your edit first?

If still have no clues, try Method Profile your app or your keyboard and check who's calling setInputType() kind-a method can be helpful.